# Group multiple events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Interestingly enough, the two solutions posted work, however, perhaps its the CSS I've written, but the links do not appear when the hamburger button is pressed. As well the background-color is taking up a large portion of screen when the .nav .open is not enabled.

________________CSS is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navigation {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: .75rem;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .navigation:nth-child(3) {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .nav {
        flex-direction: column;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .nav a {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: .5rem;
    }
    .nav a:first-child {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
    .fa-bars {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .onav {
        margin-left: 2.5rem;
    }
}

.header {
    background: #252525;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 1.75rem;
}

.container {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 236px;
    max-height: 24px;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
}

.open {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav a {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #fff;
}

.onav {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

________________ORG POST:

Hi — am attempting to set this navigation up so that when clicked 2 things happen, navigation shade slides down (slideToggle), and navigation links appear (toggleClass) on one go. When link is clicked, navigation shade slides back up, removing class. Unsure if that is even the proper way to do these things. Aware that the jQuery below is not even close to correct, could someone guide me on the proper way to execute this?

— Thanks

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta lang="eng">
    <meta name description="">
    <meta name title="">
    <title></title>
    <!-- MOBILE META -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test_styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navigation">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="name" style="font-size:24px; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:2px;" />
            <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button" class="onav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <div class="nav">
                <a href="">link 1</a>
                <a href="">link 2</a>
                <a href="">link 3</a>
                <a href="">link 4</a>
                <a href="">link 5</a>
                <a href="">link 6</a>
                <a href="">link 7</a>
                <a href="">link 8</a>
                <a href="">link 9</a>
                <a href="">link 10</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#trigger-overlay").on("click", function() {
            $(".nav").toggleClass("open").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $('.nav a').click(function() {
            $(this).slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply allow the same code to run when either the nav button or a link is clicked.

replace

```
$(this).slideUp();
```

with

```
$(".nav").toggleClass("open").slideToggle("slow");
```

Here is the complete code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#trigger-overlay").on("click", function() {
            $(".nav").toggleClass("open").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $('.nav a').click(function() {
            $(".nav").toggleClass("open").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navigation">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="name" style="font-size:24px; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:2px;" />
            <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button" class="onav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <div class="nav">
                <a href="#">link 1</a>
                <a href="#">link 2</a>
                <a href="#">link 3</a>
                <a href="#">link 4</a>
                <a href="#">link 5</a>
                <a href="#">link 6</a>
                <a href="#">link 7</a>
                <a href="#">link 8</a>
                <a href="#">link 9</a>
                <a href="#">link 10</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```